# How to manage state of react + apollo app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, apollo, react-apollo

I'm going to use apollo js library to fetch data from graphql api, but as I can see from the docs, it's supposed to insert fetching data directly in the components via props. So my question is do I need some state managing tool like redux for my app? If yes, how can I do that in more or less idiomatic way?

Comment: Generally speaking you don't need any state management "tool" if you use graphql and apollo. Components' states are good enough. However sometimes eg. you have advanced multipage forms it's easier to store data in eg. redux store. But you can do it without state management library.

Comment: Is that because of apollo's caching mechanism I don't need a state?

Comment: imho mainly because of passing queries results as props to components in really nice way but also caching mechanism and eg. readFragment can substitute mapStateToProps

Comment: thanks for the clarification.